# LINQ to SQL - Sql tuning

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sqlmetal

I am using LINQ to SQL for much of the data access layer and am trying to view and tune the underlying SQL used.  Does anyone know a good mechanism to intercept the SQL used by C# LINQ and/or replace it with a more tuned query?

Comment: Is there a way to replace the generated SQL at runtime?

Comment: I guess you could replace poor performing LINQ queries with [custom stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386946.aspx), which would obviously involve replacing the LINQ query in C# (rather than merely 'replacing' the LINQ query's SQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to analyze and optimize your LINQ. You can display generated SQL and check also how long certain query took.

You can also use it with existing project that uses Entity Framework. See more details [here](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx).

Comment: Loving LINQPad right now - I did not even know it existing this morning.

Comment: Great to hear that you like it also! I actually found the program few weeks ago and I have been using it now for testing C# methods, writing LINQ and doing database queries (I like LINQ syntax more than SQL). It is very helpful also here in StackOverflow because you can very easily test some C# source code or write an example.

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext itself has a Log property which is a TextWriter, using this you can write out to whatever you want be it the framework TraceClasses or something Like Log4Net or NLog